# Keep a table header at top of grid when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know there are multiple way to write this, I have tried (fixed) and since I am not familiar with front end code I am finding this challenging. I found that placing the table header in a table itself and the table body in a table scrollable -y worked but I also need to have columns line up based on a drop down selection from the user and if I could avoid having to do that it would improve the look but I have yet to find a fix.

```
         </div>
      <div v-if="globals.showStructure === true" style="border:1px solid red; max-height:500px;overflow-y:scroll;position:top;" id="tableContainer2">
      <!--<div v-if="globals.showStructure === true" style="max-height:500px;overflow-y:auto" id="tableContainer2">-->
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <ul class="right-click-menu" tabindex="-1"  v-if="globals.viewActiveStructMenu === true" ref="activeStructure">
           <li v-on:click="deleteStructure()">Delete</li>
           <li v-on:click="pendStructure()">Pend</li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="right-click-menu" tabindex="-1"  v-if="globals.viewPendStructMenu === true" ref="pendStructure">
           <li v-on:click="deleteStructure()">Delete<li>
           <li v-on:click="activateStructure()">Activate</li>
          </ul>
          <thead>
            <tr>
            <th style="width: 36px;" v-if="globals.showActiveToPendCheckbox == true" >Pend </th>
            <th style="width: 38px;" v-if="globals.showActivateCheckbox == true" > Activate </th>
            <th style="width: 58px;" v-if="globals.showDeleteCheckbox == true" > Delete </th>
            <th style="width: 48px;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Super Summary Code">Sup Sum Code</th>
            <th style="width: 80px;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Super Summary Description"> Sup Sum Code Desc</th>
            <th style="width: 48px;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Summary Code">Sum Code</th>
            <th style="width: 122px;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Summary Code Description">Sum Code Desc</th>
            <th style="width: 115px;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Family Code">Fam Code</th>
            <th style="width: 81px;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Secondary Code">Sec Code</th>
            <th style="width: 180px;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Trade Item Description">GTIN Desc</th>
            <th style="width: 82px;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="GTIN">GTIN</th>
            <th style="width: 40px;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Status">Status</th>
            <th v-if="globals.showEditColumn == true" style="width: 50px;" title='Edit'>Edit</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr  v-on:mousedown="rowStructClick(fcStructureItem.gtin,false)"  v-for="(fcStructureItem, index) in filteredFamilyCodeStructure"
            :key="fcStructureItem.gtin"
            :id="fcStructureItem.gtin"
            :form.fcStructure="form.fcStructure" tabindex="-1" v-on:contextmenu="openStructMenu($event)"
            :class = "alterRowColors(index)">
              <td v-if="globals.showActiveToPendCheckbox == true">
                <input  type="checkbox" v-model="activeToPendSelected" :value="fcStructureItem.gtin" number>
                </input>
              </td>
              <td v-if="globals.showActivateCheckbox == true">
                <input  type="checkbox" v-model="activateSelected" :value="fcStructureItem.gtin" number>
                </input>
              </td>
              <td v-if="globals.showDeleteCheckbox == true">
                <input  type="checkbox" v-model="deleteSelected" :value="fcStructureItem.gtin" number>
                </input>
              </td>
            <td>
              <span >{{ fcStructureItem.superSummaryCd }}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span >{{ fcStructureItem.superSummaryDesc }}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span >{{ fcStructureItem.summaryCd }}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span >{{ fcStructureItem.summaryDesc }}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span>{{ fcStructureItem.couponFamilyCode }}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span>{{ fcStructureItem.oldCouponFamilyCode }}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span >{{ fcStructureItem.tradeItemDescription }}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span >{{ fcStructureItem.gtin }}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span >{{ fcStructureItem.status }}</span>
            </td>
            <div v-if="globals.showEditButton == true" >
              <td>
                <span>
                  <button  class="btn btn-primary"  title="edit structure item" v-on:click="editStructure(fcStructureItem)">
                    <span> Edit </span>
                  </button>
                  </span>
              </td>
            </div>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <table id="PlaceHolder2"  class="table table-bordered"></table>

        <!-- new grid code is between here>-->

      </div>
```

Help on entering the CSS in here would be great if needed.

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this previously having a fixed table layout CSS (or only 1 column is allowed to grow for width), and you do a pair of tables. one only has headers, the other only has rows and is inside a scrollable DIV.  This was admittedly ~10years ago and IE6 compatible...

These days you should be able to set a CSS for your `<tbody>` to have `overflow-x:none` and `overflow-y:scroll` (or auto if you want no scrollbar with short data lists) as long as your `<tr>` are inside your `<tbody>`

(Edited to add `code tag` formatting to stop html tags vanishing from the text!)

Comment: There are styles inside the HTML as well as CSS at the bottom. the style at the HTML level (rather the consumers want the table to be "max-hight:500px; overfloy-y:scroll; position:top;". Hince the reason I will be needing a scroll bar, or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Sorry - I hadn't spotted it had hidden half my words, might make more sense now.. (Edited to add `code tag` formatting to stop html tags vanishing from the text!)

Comment: I figured something happened like that I edited my question as well, I believe I have overflow-x: scroll in the table. There is also a bootstrap attribute in table class. I have tried to put the header in a table and the content in a table seperate but the content doesnt line up with the header once I do that but the header does stay in one place. Honestly I was given this, the main developers cant fix the issue because its all a hack so if I can find a something similar to solve it that would awesome. I have tried about everything I have found on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the new `position: sticky` property.
When the page would scroll over the table header, it sticks to the top of the page and stays there.

For this, you have to define a `top` value, that specifies the offset (probably 0)

But be careful, sticky does not work in every browser and is especially buggy in tables: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

```css
thead {
  /* position: sticky; and top: 0; are the only needed properties here. The rest is for showcase only. */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
}

th {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  height: 200px
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This would not work for my table, the max-height:500. There are two top containers above the table that have collapsible content that filter what the user wants to see in the grid. I hate to say it but the page was really developed hacky like so anything that would keep the header at the top and keep the content in the grid the same size as the header columns would be a life saver.